# FORGE Viewer performance and error issue with big size file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I had translated 500 Mb sized NWD file and tried to load it to FORGE Viewer. (I believe the NWD file has may graphical elements and objects)

It takes around 4 to 5 Min. for loading which is slow after cache initialization and error occurs as below images after blinking web browser.

[error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsNEJ.jpg)

[error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GECVb.jpg)

Any advice or guide resolving this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options to consider when dealing with *really* large models:

1. Use the `Autodesk.MemoryLimited` viewer extension to control the amount of memory allocated for the model (to avoid browser crashes or context losses): https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit.
2. Use the new [SVF2](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format) file format which can detect and remove many duplicate geometries, decreasing the total amount of geometry that must downloaded from the servers and sent to the GPU.
3. As a last resort - something our customers also do - try splitting the Navisworks design into multiple models, for example by area or discipline, and then load it on demand.